# Passing array of strings to vector C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am tring to push an array of strings to a vector, like this:

```
 string []URL = {"www.facebook.com","www.orkut.com","www.yahoo.com"};
 Int32 result = URL.Length;
 SetPolicyURL( URL,result);

 SetPolicyURL( char * URLpolicy[], __int32 noURL)
 {
__int32 i  = 0;

while ( i< noURL)
{
    char buf[2512] = {0};

    URLvector.push_back(URLpolicy[i]);
    sprintf( buf," noURL = %d URLpolicy[%d] = %s  URLvector[%d] = %s", noURL,  i,URLpolicy[i] ,i, URLvector.at(i).c_str());


    MessageBoxA(NULL, buf , 0, MB_ICONERROR);

    ++i;
}
```

}

But when I try to display the elements of the vector, I am only getting the first array element twice, and the 2nd element of the array in position 3.  I am not getting whyy this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
URLvector.assign(URLpolicy,URLpolicy+noURL) ;
```

can be used to pass the array of strings to a vector.

Answer (score 0):

The follow code should do what you want without a loop. C++ allows you to insert an array as if it were an iterator for vectors. This method is less complex and error prone.

```
URLvector.insert(URLpolicy, URLpolicy+noURL );
```

also change

```
SetPolicyURL( char * URLpolicy[], __int32 noURL);
```

to

```
SetPolicyURL( string[] URLpolicy, __int32 noURL);
```

A `char *[]` is not the same as a `string[]` That's what causing your original issue.

Comment: URLvector.insert(URL, URL+noURL ); inserts vector to a vector i want to insert array to a vector

Comment: oh I see, I wasn't using the local version `URLpolicy`. So now it should insert your array `URLpolicy` into the vector `URLvector`.

Comment: ya i want to insert the elements of array into my vector